# MySQL column name for importing User Email into wp_users

Tags: mysql, wordpress, csv

I am trying to import a CSV file into WordPress. It seems to work just fine but I cannot figure out the name of the field for email. I have tried"Email" and I also try "user_email". Neither seem to work. So my question is is there a way to figure out what the name of this header needs to be in order for the system to import this Field.

I have looked at the wp_users table in PHPMyAdmin in the name of that header is "user_mail" but yet when I put this in the CSV file to import none of the email addresses are imported. I am not an expert at database but this is as far as I have been able to get. Any suggestions?

Many thanks,
Houston

Comment: how do you want to import, with what? with a plugin?

Comment: If you're importing this into the database, it's definitely `user_email`, not `user_mail`.